# Is it possible to load part of svg file using snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have svg

```
<svg><g id="g1">polygons here...</g><g id="g2">polygons here...</g></svg>
```

Now I'm loading using snap.svg

```
<svg id="svg" width="1024"></svg>
    var s = Snap("#svg");
    s.attr({ viewBox: "0 0 1024 3250" });
    Snap.load("URLHERE", function(f){
        s.append(f);
    }) ;
```

Is it possible to take only part os file and lod it like **f.select("#g1")** and than append only that part os file ?

Answer (score 1):

Well i found solution.
I just take the f object get part of svg i need and then append it like so:

```
var g = f.node.childNodes[4].querySelector("#HERE");
```

and after append and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **implementation** of `Snap.load`:

```
Snap.load = function (url, callback, scope) {
    Snap.ajax(url, function (req) {
        var f = Snap.parse(req.responseText);
        scope ? callback.call(scope, f) : callback(f);
    });
};
```

It 'loads' the svg with an ajax call and delegates the loading part to `Snap.parse`.

You could **implement your own** version which parses the xml and extracts parts of the svg to be parsed by `Snap.parse()`.

Something like:

```
myLoad = function (url, callback, scope, WHAT_TO_LOAD) {
    Snap.ajax(url, function (req) {
        var svgDataToParse = req.responseText;
        var result = "";
        // DO SOMETHING WITH svgDataToParse
        var f = Snap.parse(result);
        scope ? callback.call(scope, f) : callback(f);
    });
};
```